# SharePoint Navigation Menu - Multi Level

Tags: moss, navigation, telerik

I'm looking into integrating some Telerik Components into our MOSS Installation.  I'd figure I would kill a few birds with one stone and work on the Navigation Menu first.

I'm slightly new to SharePoint, and pulling hair at some of it's oddities.

We have some requirements for our Navigation menu:

- Security Trimmed
- Multi-Level Navigation

As best as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way to get security trimming without using SharePoint's out of the box Navigation Settings.  Am I wrong?

Is there a way to get these Navigation Settings to go more than two levels deep?

#### EDITS

- I'm using the Global Navigation, located at `/ > Site Settings > Modify Navigation`

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used the Telerik control.

I suspect you should be able to accomplish this with basic properties, something like StaticDisplayLevels="2" with 2 being the number you want.

The security I believe would be handled on your datasource that the control uses.

Again, I haven't used the telerik control so I'm sure it's a bit different, looking at the product info for this control it appears to be a matter of figuring out what the properties are that you need to adjust. There must be some documentation that came with it?

Comment: The problem is, I'm handling the navigation in the Global Navigation Settings.  I do not see a StaticDisplayLevels property.

Comment: You need to modify this in the master page, it's a property of the default navigation control - not sure about telerik's one but I have to assume it has something similar or better.

Answer (score 1):

Savageguy is correct that you modify this on the datasource, an example:

```
<PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource 
    ID="MainNavigationDataSource" 
    runat="server" 
    EnableViewState="true"
    SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavSiteMapProvider"
    StartingNodeOffset="0" 
    ShowStartingNode="false" />
```

and then you can use any sort of control (databound) to render your menu. I´m using a repeater for my menu:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MenuRepeater" 
DataSourceID="MainNavigationDataSource">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not required to use any other components other than SharePoint Menu but you have to add a small piece of script in the body tag:

< body  onload="javascript:if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();">